# How to get input_shape for keras subclassed Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I'm subclassing keras model like in [tensorflow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras)

```
class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.gru = GRU(32, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
        self.dense = Dense(4, name='decoder_dense')

    def call(self, inputs):
        input, hidden = inputs
        gru_output, state = self.gru(input, initial_state=hidden)
        outputs = self.dense(gru_output)
        return outputs, state

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

 my_model = Decoder()
```

In this scenario I cannot access `my_decoder.input_shape` and get an error
`AttributeError: The layer has never been called and thus has no defined input shape.`

If I create model using keras functional API, parameter `my_model.built` is automatically set to `True` and I can access `input_shape`. It totally make sense to me, because in functional API I explicitly provide  shape to `Input()` layer

So, my question is, what should I do to be able to access `input_shape` in keras subclassed model before fitting data

Comment: May this answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194053/how-to-get-ouput-shape-of-the-layer-in-tensorflow/54194436#54194436