# AttributeError: Layer has no inbound nodes, or AttributeError: The layer has never been called

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I need a way to get the shape of output tensor for any type of layer (i.e. Dense, Conv2D, etc) in TensorFlow. According to documentation, there is `output_shape` property which solves the problem. However every time I access it I get `AttributedError`.

Here is code sample showing the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


x = np.arange(0, 8, dtype=np.float32).reshape((1, 8))
x = tf.constant(value=x, dtype=tf.float32, verify_shape=True)

dense = tf.layers.Dense(units=2)

out = dense(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    res = sess.run(fetches=out)
    print(res)
    print(dense.output_shape)
```

The `print(dense.output_shape)` statement will produce error message:

```
AttributeError: The layer has never been called and thus has no defined output shape.
```

or `print(dense.output)` will produce:

```
AttributeError('Layer ' + self.name + ' has no inbound nodes.')
AttributeError: Layer dense_1 has no inbound nodes.
```

Is there any way to fix the error?

**P.S.:**
I know that in example above I can get shape of output tensor via `out.get_shape()`. However I want to know why `output_shape` property doesn't work and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### TL;DR

*How can I fix it?* Define an input layer:

```
x = tf.keras.layers.Input(tensor=tf.ones(shape=(1, 8)))
dense = tf.layers.Dense(units=2)

out = dense(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    res = sess.run(fetches=out)
    print(dense.output_shape) # shape = (1, 2)
```

---

Accordint to Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/), if a layer has a single **node**, you can get its input tensor, output tensor, input shape and output shape via:

- layer.input
- layer.output
- layer.input_shape
- layer.output_shape

But in the above example, when we call `layer.output_shape` or other attributes, it throws exceptions that seem a bit strange.

If we go deep in the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L917), the error caused by **inbound nodes**.

```
if not self._inbound_nodes:
  raise AttributeError('The layer has never been called '
                       'and thus has no defined output shape.')
```

What these [inbound nodes](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L1179) are?

> A **Node** describes the **connectivity between two layers**. Each time a layer is connected to some new input,
> a node is added to *layer._inbound_nodes*.
> Each time the output of a layer is used by another layer,
> a node is added to *layer._outbound_nodes*.

As you can see in the above, when `self._inbounds_nodes` is None it throws an exception. ***This means when a layer is not connected to the input layer or more generally, none of the previous layers are connected to an input layer, `self._inbounds_nodes` is empty which caused the problem***.

Notice that `x` in your example, is a tensor and not an input layer. See another example for more clarification:

```
x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(8,))
dense = tf.layers.Dense(units=2)

out = dense(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    res = sess.run(fetches=out, feed_dict={x: np.ones(shape=(1, 8))})
    print(res)
    print(res.shape)  # shape = (1,2)
    print(dense.output_shape)  # shape = (None,2)
```

It is perfectly fine because the input layer is defined.

---

Note that, in your example, `out` is a tensor. The difference between the `tf.shape()` function and the `.shape` =(`get_shape()`) is:

> `tf.shape(x)` returns a 1-D integer tensor representing the dynamic
> shape of x. A dynamic shape will be known only at graph execution time.
>
> `x.shape` returns a Python tuple representing the static
> shape of x. A static shape, known at graph definition time.

Read more about tensor shape at: https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/2018/07/28/understanding-tensorflow-tensors-shape-static-dynamic/

Comment: I'm not sure your answer helps me with my issue. `tf.shape` works with tensors  and `tf.layers.Dense` is not a tensor but layer (i.e. subclass of `tf.layers.Layer` and `tf.keras.layers.Layer`. As for `x.shape` attribute I'm not sure what you mean. According to [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/Dense) Dense layer doesn't have such attribute.

As for dynamic shape it's not the case in my sample. If I will add `tf.shape(out).eval()` inside the `with` statement in my example then it would return `[1 2]` which means output tensor is of the static shape.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really did help.