# Variable size mismatch between x.shape and tf.shape(x)?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to understand tf code and for this I am printing out shapes of tensors. For the following code

```
print(x.shape)
print(tf.shape(x))
```

I get output

```
(?, 32, 32, 3)
Tensor("input/Shape:0", shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
```

It does not make a lot of sense. Based on what I found online tf.shape(x) can be used to dynamically get the size for the batch. But it gives rather wrong output - 4. I am not sure where this `(4,)` is coming from and how to get the right value for my tensor.

Comment: Last part of the answer may solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194436/1462770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the two results are the same. `4` is the shape of `(?,32,32,3)`.

`x.shape()` returns a tuple, and you can get shape without `sess.run()`. You can use `as_list()` to convert it into a list.

`tf.shape(x)` returns a tensor, and you need to run `sess.run()` to get the the actual number.

An example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,32,32,3),dtype=tf.float32)
print(x.shape)
print(tf.shape(x))

dim = tf.shape(x)
dim0 = tf.shape(x)[0]

with tf.Session()as sess:
    dim,dim0 = sess.run([dim,dim0],feed_dict={x:np.random.uniform(size=(100,32,32,3))})
    print(dim)
    print(dim0)

#print
(?, 32, 32, 3)
Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
[100  32  32   3]
100
```