# Keras embedding positional information

Tags: indexing, keras, embedding

I am trying to embedding the positional information 'index' to some vector and use in Keras, for instance

```
inputs = Input(shape=(23,))
```

Which usually 23 represents as the number of features. I want to embed the position of the features to be one dimentional vector, from position 0 to position 22.

But I don't know how to get the position index of the features (I want something like 'enumerate' function for keras layer), I added

```
pos = K.constant([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]])
embedding_pos = Embedding(23, 1)(pos)
```

And I actually this embedding_pos to multiply with inputs and do the rest of the algorithms go on.

But I get this message

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

If I get rid of that embedding layer and multiply layer, the algorithm works fine. How am I supposed to get the embedding vectors using the position index of the features of inputs?

======

Adding more information, I moved around the layers to see the model.summary(), it seems like it has the embedding_pos = [None, 1] shape, which is missing batch size.

I don't think it is good to use 'Constant'. I'd like to know if there is some kind of 'enumerate' function for keras layer

=====

By the request, example inputs is like this

> batch_size x number_of_features = 1 x 10

```
[[1.0, 4719.0, 0.0001, 472818.44, 958, 6402818., 1.828, 24.321, 55.0, 127.44]]
```

and so on...

I want to get the index of the features

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

to use this value as the input for Embedding.

But if I make it with constant, it doesn't know the batch size.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you want. Do you want a hard coded embedding like one-hot-encoding? Could you provide one concrete example input array and on concrete example output matrix of the embedding layer?

Comment: I added some example for you

Comment: More likely, I want to know how to do the emedding with each feature's positional information

Comment: See this thread for inbounds_node https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194436/1462770